# При использовании OpenCommPort линкер выдаёт ошибку unresolved external

Tags: winapi, c++builder

Использовав API функцию OpenCommPort, компиляция прошла успешно, но линкер выдаёт ошибку:

> Unresolved external 'OpenCommPort' referenced from...

Как исправить ошибку?

Версия Билдера 10.3.2.

Comment: https://blablacode.ru/programmirovanie/392 изучи материал по ссылке

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Как открывать COM порт через CreateFile я знаю. Меня интересует именно работа указанной API.

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали. Данные функции работают только на Windows 10. Чтобы их использовать, надо добавить в проект lib-файл, который получить из KernelBase.dll с помощью утилиты implib.